# Why internet inbound rule for Azure app services does not work?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network, azure-nsg

I have configured an Vitualnetwork let us call it "WorkVirtualNetwork" and it has two subnets "API" and "APImanagement".I have created an azure web app service and assigned the "API" subnet to it.

I have created a network security group NSG1 and assigned it to "API" subnet so that no calls can be made from the internet but only within the virtual network "WorkVirtualNetwork"

[image]

But I tried the access the web app services URL ..https://XXXX.azurewebsites.net/ from a browser. I am still able to access the same.Ideally, I was expected that it should be blocked as I have assigned an inbound restriction to it. Is there anything that I am missing in configurations?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure **Access Restriction** of **App Service Networking** section, not VNet integration. Set it up so that only access from VNet is accepted.

Vnet integration is for your app service to be able to connect with internal resources inside of VNet, not other way around.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not so sure it is possible. Please refer to the article below -

> Regardless of the version used, VNet Integration gives your web app
>   access to resources in your virtual network but doesn't grant inbound
>   private access to your web app from the virtual network. Private site
>   access refers to making your app only accessible from a private
>   network such as from within an Azure virtual network. VNet Integration
>   is only for making outbound calls from your app into your VNet.

[web-sites-integrate-with-vnet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet)